# Wordpress accessing 404 template for missing page elements?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tweaking a Wordpress site, the pages have a few missing elements. Images, for example. I notice that because of this, the theme's 404 file is being invoked for each missing element.

**Theme 404.php**

```
Utils::error_log('Hello 404');
get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div class="primary-inner">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <!-- etc -->
```

My error_log is full of "Hello 404" even though I'm not on a 404 page.

This seems, not good? All of the sidebars and header/footer code in the 404.php theme file is being run "in the background" for every missing element on a page?

**Printing out $_SERVER shows:**

```
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) PHP/7.2.18
[REQUEST_URI] => /thumbs/image.jpg
// etc...
```

So yeah, image.jpg isn't found but why is this triggering Wordpress to run the code of 404.php? Seems like a negative performance hit if there's a couple missing images on a page and users are hitting it hundreds of times an hour, etc.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or even a hacky way of determining if the request for 404 page is legitimate before running the entire file's code?

Comment: This is the way the internet works.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: It might be how your web server is configured. If it is not configured to serve static content directly or is configures to pass ALL requests to WordPress, I think could happen.

If it could, then it is your browser requesting those missing (static) pieces of content and being routed through WordPress, which leads to the 404 routings.

I suppose you actually might want to have missing pieces of content logged as 404, as they are in fact 'misses', but not as WordPress misses.

**If you are using Nginx:**

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

```
location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

The important but I think is this: try the uri, try with slash and only then hit PHP.

**For Apache**

have a look under #3: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/rewritecond-and-rewriterule-tricks-for-htaccess/

This is what tells Apache to only proceed with PHP if the file is not found.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: interesting thank you, unfortunately I'm using Apache though

Comment: I added an Apache sample as well. Maybe you can tell a bit more about how your site is hosted? Of paste your config here? Others or I might be able to pinpoint your issue more precicely.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but nothing. That's basically what the default WP htaccess file looks like, except without the QSA part. Is there anything specific about the server setup you/others would like to know that could help? Maybe this is just default behavior for all WP setups, just seems strange to me, I noticed some widgets were being tapped to render 5+ times a page load and I couldn't figure out why, turns out the 404 template is doing it - somewhere - behind the scenes.